# What is the adjective for a marriage with multiple children?

Tags: adjectives

I want to get across the meaning of a marriage that has produced multiple children with an adjective. Would I say `a multi-child marriage`, `a multi-children marriage`, or something else? I'm not quite sure what would make the most sense.

Comment: I don't know of a way to make that clear that does not include a list of the children. I look forward to some vocabulary to be suggested.

Comment: Do you think there is such word? **Fruitful** and **productive** are sometimes used, but they are euphemisms. **Procreative** would be correct, but it's a bit obscure and we don't use it. Cunicular means rabbit-like, but we certainly don't use *that*.

Comment: It’s strange to be talking about this in terms of the marriage, I’d expect the word, if there is one, to describe a ***family*** with more than one child.

Comment: *Fecund* is the word that comes to mind. https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=fecund

Comment: @Xanne: *Fecund*'s a good word. I forgot that. Fructifying is another, but it's less idiomatic.

Comment: So would `The man had a fecund marriage.` work?

Comment: That's not idiomatic, @Stanley Y. I don't think there's a word meaning *children-producing*. I would simply describe it. *Their marriage produced many children* or (if you really want to) *Their marriage was fruitful and they had many children.* Religious folk would no doubt say, *...and they were blessed with many children.*